# how store UIColor in string format on core data?

Tags: ios

How to store colour in core data.

```
UIColor *color=[UIColor grayColor];
NSData *theData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
```

I tried it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your UIColor to Components and then store it:

```
UIColor *orgColor = [UIColor blackColor];
const CGFloat *colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(orgColor.CGColor);// RGBA
NSInteger count = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(orgColor.CGColor);
CGFloat r, g, b, a; // save to db
if (count == 2) {
    r = g = b = colorComponents[0];
    a = colorComponents[1];
}else if (count == 4) {
    r = colorComponents[0];
    g = colorComponents[1];
    b = colorComponents[2];
    a = colorComponents[3];
}else{
    NSLog(@"What is this?");
}
```

then you can convert r.g.b.a back to your UIColor object:

```
UIColor *newColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
```

If necessary, u can conv rgb to NSInteger with 0xFF for Coredata:

```
NSInteger colorInteger = ((NSInteger)(r*0xFF)<<(8*3)) 
                       + ((NSInteger)(g*0xFF)<<(8*2)) 
                       + ((NSInteger)(b*0xFF)<<(8*1)) 
                       + ((NSInteger)(a*0xFF)<<(8*0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it. It works perfectly.

```
NSManagedObject *newDevice;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)])

 {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    }

    return context;

}


CGColorRef colorRef = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;

NSString *colorString = [CIColorcolorWithCGColor:colorRef].stringRepresentation;

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ImageDetail" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageView.image);

[newDevice setValue:colorString forKey:@"color"];
```